# Recommend me a software that detects MCQs or MSQs from pdf file

Tags: open-source

I have a [pdf](https://jam.iitr.ac.in/assets/JAMPreviousYearsQuestionPapers/JAM2021/QPs/PH2021.pdf) of MCQs and MSQs.  I want to solve those questions on my PC only means I want to tick the correct option on my PC only. I don't want to do it in my notebook. Is there any software for this that can auto-detect MCQs or MSQs and I could customize it like time limit and features like leave for later review, etc.? I know there are some apps that generate MCQs question paper but in these kind of apps we have to manually type or copy-paste the questions and options with one or more correct option(s) in it. I want to automate this work. Is it possible? If there's software of this kind, please recommend me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which software in which to upload mcqs scanned pdf and get answer option of each question in file?

Comment: @EmmanuelNdayambaje please read the question again.